# Is there a clustering method that can find an interpretable optimal subspace?

Tags: cluster-analysis

I'm looking for a clustering method than can find an interpretable optimal subspace.For example, if I have a dataset consistes of some features [feature_1, feature_2,...,feature_n], after clusering, I can get a clustering result and a subspace [feature_3, feature_6,...,feature_9], this subspace can interpret why any one of clustering can be clustered together.

I've tried subkmeans, it is similar with PCA, but subkmeans will transform the original dataset, although it can find an optimal subspace. Since subkmeans transformed my dataset that result in I can't find the corresponding features(that is subspace I need), so I what to ask is there a clustering method that can find this subspace.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you google a little bit you will find plenty of subspace clustering methods that select features relevant for the cluster.

See [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering_high-dimensional_data).